# Why don't contributors get author attribution for Drupal core issues?

Tags: community-official-site, version-control

I'm looking now [a commit](https://www.drupal.org/node/2796151#comment-11752815) in the [Date range separator should be translatable](https://www.drupal.org/node/2796151) issue and I don't see the commit message like:

```
alexpott committed a55967d on 8.3.x authored by mpdonadio
```

And mpdonadio has submitted [a working patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2796151#comment-11752597) but the message is:

```
alexpott committed a55967d on 8.3.x
```

So, I search in other issues to see what happens and I don't see any authored in message when the issue is related to Drupal core.

I remember that when I create a patch to [Drupal Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_entity) module the maintainer recognized my work:

```
clemens.tolboom committed f594060 on 8.x-6.x authored by adriancid
```

So, why don't contributors get author attribution for Drupal core issues?

Comment: Many people worked on that issue "Issue #2796151 by mpdonadio, jhedstrom, myLies, vijaycs85, lomasr, alexpott, Gábor Hojtsy, penyaskito, catch, xjm: Date range separator should be translatable".  I started to write up an answer and then realized that I don't think this is officially documented so I don't want to give out wrong information.  IIRC, part of the problem has to do with git only allowing a single "author" for a patch.

Comment: @mpdonadio and if only one user create the issue and publish the only patch that solve the problem?

Comment: @Adrian Cid Almaguer, this would be unfairly to those who work on other "multiuser" issues.

Comment: @ya.teck I just trying to know how this works.